# Evaluate $\int _0^1\:\frac{2-x^2}{(1+x)\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx$

Tags: integration

> Evaluate $$\int _0^1\:\frac{2-x^2}{(1+x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

$$
\int _0^1\:\frac{2-x^2}{(1+x)\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx = \int_0^1 \bigg[\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^{3/2}\sqrt{1+x}}\bigg] \, dx=\int_0^1[f(x)+f'(x)]\,dx
$$
Does making it into the above final form helps somehow solve the given definite integral ?

**Note:** The solution given is $\pi/2$

Comment: What about contour integration?

Comment: The $f(x)+f'(x)$ form would help if you had $e^x$ as a factor since $(e^xf(x))'=e^x(f(x)+f'(x))$. But you don't have this here.

Comment: Why not trigonometric substitution? It gives a not too messy integral which indeed yields $\;\pi/2\;$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\sin t$. Then,

$$\int _0^1 \frac{2-x^2}{\left(1+x\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
=\int _0^1\left(\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}}
+\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+x}\right)dx$$
$$=\int_0^{\pi/2} \left( \frac{dt}{1+\sin t}+1-\sin t\right)dt$$
$$=\left(-\frac{\cos t}{1+\sin t} + t + \cos t\right)_0^{\pi/2}=\frac\pi2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x=:\sin u\implies dx=\cos u\,du\implies\int_0^1\frac{2-x^2}{(1+x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2-\sin^2u}{(1+\sin u)}\,du=$$

$$=\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac1{1+\sin u}+1-\sin u\right)du=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1-\sin u}{\cos^2u}+\left.\frac\pi2+\cos u\right|_0^{\pi/2}=$$

$$=\left.\left(\tan u-\frac1{\cos u}\right)\right|_0^{\pi/2}+\frac\pi2-1=\frac\pi2$$

since

$$\lim_{u\to\frac\pi2^-}\left(\tan u-\frac1{\cos u}\right)=\lim_{u\to\frac\pi2^-}\frac{\sin u-1}{\cos u}\stackrel{\text{L'Hospital}}=0$$